# Create Normal Curve using TabPy

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api, tabpy

I have before made Normal curves using the amazing blog by Robin Kennedy:
https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/blog/2013/11/fitting-normal-curve-histogram

But when it comes to TabPy, I am failing to do so. As using Python codes inside Tableau needs some tweaking to do, some of the basic functions of Python fail in Tableau.

Even if I go step by step with the blog and manipulating the code as TabPy needs me to work, the final formula to make the curve -

```
(1 / ([St Dev] * SQRT(2*PI()))) * EXP(-((ATTR([Profit Bin]) – [Mean])^2 / (2*[St Dev]^2))) * [Profit Bin Size]* TOTAL (SUM([Number of Records]))
```

is rather getting difficult for me to recreate.

What I wrote till now is -

```
SCRIPT_REAL("
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math


sigma = maths.sqrt(_arg1)
x = np.linspace(_arg2 - 3*_arg3, _arg2 + 3*_arg3, 100)


", FLOAT([Variance]), FLOAT([Mean]), FLOAT([Std Dev]) )
```

I am clueless how to proceed next, I mean how to plot that out. Any advice in this?

I have made the histogram using Tableau bins but I need to make the curve using Python.